# 400 error respond code

Tags: java, url, https

I've got 400 error. There is something wrong after AND..

URL that is not working:

```
URL url = new URL(SeleniumProperties.getUrlRefreshVer() + "/services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+QPConfig_Decimal_NetPrice__c+FROM+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c+" + "WHERE+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c+=+'" + quoteId + "' + "AND+Apttus_QPConfig__ChargeType__c+=+'Freight Fee'");
```

when I use below it is working:

```
URL url = new URL(SeleniumProperties.getUrlRefreshVer() + "/services/data/v36.0/query/?q= SELECT+QPConfig_Decimal_NetPrice__c+FROM+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c+" + "WHERE+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c+=+'" + quoteId + "');
```

there is something wrong after AND

Can anybody help?

Comment: I missed + in Freight Fee, so it is now 'Freight+Fee' and it is working

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have are missing a quote mark in your string concatenation:

```
URL url = new URL(SeleniumProperties.getUrlRefreshVer() + "/services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+QPConfig_Decimal_NetPrice__c+FROM+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c+" + "WHERE+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c+=+'" + quoteId + "' + AND+Apttus_QPConfig__ChargeType__c+=+'Freight Fee'");
```

Comment: Doesn't that make `Freight Fee` unescaped? As if it was a variable.

Answer (score 0):

[400 Bad Request HTTP Error](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request)

> The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that
>   indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by
>   the client due to invalid syntax

The important part in that quote is the **invalid syntax** part, which means you're not forming the URL correctly, and to prevent that, you should use a proper IDE with highlighting (or even Stackoverflow code blocks) to make it obvious for you, through coloring, where the syntax error lies.

With that said, a couple things are wrong in your URL, syntax wise, use this instead:

```
URL url = new URL(SeleniumProperties.getUrlRefreshVer() + "/services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+QPConfig_Decimal_NetPrice__c+FROM+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c+" + "WHERE+Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c+=+'" + quoteId + "' + AND+Apttus_QPConfig__ChargeType__c+=+'Freight Fee'");
```